# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'r' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
double Razv(double b,double a,double x,double y, double z, int& n)
{
    double r;
    if ((pow(abs(x),y))<z)
    {
        r= x*x*x + abs(a)*sin(y);
        n=1;
    }
    else    
    if(((pow(abs(x),y))>=z) && ((pow(abs(x),y))<=(z+10)))   
    {
       double r=x; double r1 = y; double r2 = z;
       if(r1>r)r=r1;
       if(r2>r)r=r2;
       n=2;
    }   
    else 
    {
       double r = pow(x, 1/3);
       double r1 = b*y; 
       double r2 = pow(abs(z), 1/2);
       if(r1<r)r=r1;
       if(r2<r)r=r2;
       n = 3;
   }
   return r; 
}
```

Ввод, вывод и main в других файлах.Но там нет ошибок

Comment: а вы инициализируйте его, потому что условие может  и не выполняться и ваш double r останется не инициализированным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double Razv(double b, double a, double x, double y, double z, int& n)
{
    double r;
    if ((pow(abs(x), y)) < z)
    {
        r = x * x * x + abs(a) * sin(y);
        n = 1;
    }
    else
        if (((pow(abs(x), y)) >= z) && ((pow(abs(x), y)) <= (z + 10)))
        {
            //не объявляйте новую одноименную переменную
            // а инициализируйте уже объявленную
            r = x; double r1 = y; double r2 = z;
            if (r1 > r)r = r1;
            if (r2 > r)r = r2;
            n = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            r = pow(x, 1 / 3);
            double r1 = b * y;
            double r2 = pow(abs(z), 1 / 2);
            if (r1 < r)r = r1;
            if (r2 < r)r = r2;
            n = 3;
        }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Как легкое дополнение для понимания ТС - скажем, объявление в каком-то блоке `esle` новой переменной `r` приводит к тому, что вычисленное значение будет потеряно, а возвращаться будет совсем другое `r` - объявление скроет то значение, которое объявлено вне блока...

Comment: @Harry, думаю могли бы оформить это в виде ответа. Мой ответ не обьясняет причину, он мне самому не нравится(я бы удалил свой)

Comment: Лучше вы допишите это в свой ответ, хорошо?